# WM_INPUT messages blocked by Device Manager

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, touchscreen, raw-input

I have an application which monitors touchscreen messages in a Windows tablet. I want to wake up some hardware when the user touches the touchscreen. I have used the approach from [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard).

I call RegisterRawInputDevices() to register to receive touchscreen messages:

```
        var rid = new RawInputDevice[1];
        rid[0].UsagePage = 13;     // HidUsagePage.Digitizer
        rid[0].Usage = 4;          // HidUsage.TouchScreen
        rid[0].Flags = 0x00000100; // RawInputDeviceFlags.InputSink
        rid[0].Target = this.Handle;
        if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])))
        {
            // report error
        }
```

I then receive WM_INPUT messages in my message pump:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
      switch (message.Msg)
        {
            case WmInput:
                // handle touch messages
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
```

This works fine most of the time. I can touch anywhere on the screen and my application gets a WM_INPUT message. But if I run Windows Device Manager, I do not get touch messages when I touch inside the Device Manager.

I have tested this with the Microsoft Digiinfo tool, and it has the same behaviour.

I also see the same behaviour with the Computer Management application.

Is there a class of applications that can block WM_INPUT messages? Is there some way around this problem? I may just have to accept this behaviour, but I would still like to understand it.

Comment: It isn't very crystal what you are doing.  But in general you can't observe or generate messages intended for elevated apps.  Like Device Manager.  Named UIPI, User Interface Privilege Isolation, the lesser known twin of UAC.  Run your app elevated as well and good odds that it now works.  Bypassing UIPI requires a manifest with uiAccess = true, a valid code signing certificate and an install location in c:\windows or c:\program files.

Comment: Thanks @HanPassant, I can confirm that running my app as an administrator, I now receive WM_INPUT messages. I will look into your suggestion about signing and installation.